# Proof of equivalence theorem using equational calculus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have to show the following theorem:

$p\vee \neg p \equiv ((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge\neg r)$

I have proved

$((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge\neg r) \implies p\vee \neg p$

It is true because we apply the definition of the implication, then we have:

$[((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge\neg r)] \vee (p\vee \neg p)$

By applying the negation rule, we have:

$[((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge\neg r)] \vee (true)$

And finally, by using the dominance rule of OR, we have:

$true$

**BUT** I have not been able to solve the other way:

$p\vee \neg p \implies ((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge\neg r)$

I have tried with this:

$\Big \langle \implies definition \Big \rangle$

$\Big \langle DeMorgan, and \wedge negation \Big \rangle$

$false \vee ((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge\neg r)$

$\Big \langle \vee identity  \Big \rangle$

$((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge\neg r)$

$\Big \langle \wedge/\vee distribution \Big \rangle$

$((p \vee q)\wedge \neg (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r)))\vee (\neg p \wedge (\neg q \vee \neg r))$

That's my solution progress up to this moment.

Some suggestions, tips, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of solving this, is to treat it as a simplification problem.  And here it seems most appropriate to simplify both sides separately, using the basic laws of logic.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

The left hand side is immediately equivalent to $\;\true\;$, by the law of the excluded middle.  The right hand side we simplify as follows:
$$\calc
    \tag{RHS}
    \Big((p \lor q) \land \lnot \big(\lnot p \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot r)\big)\Big) \;\lor\; (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot r)
\op\equiv\hint{left part: simplify using DeMorgan}
    \Big((p \lor q) \land \big(p \lor (q \land r)\big)\Big) \;\lor\; (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot r)
\op\equiv\hints{left part: extract common $\;p \lor {}\;$;}\hint{right part: extract common $\;\lnot p \land {}\;$}
    \big(p \lor (q \land q \land r)\big) \;\lor\; \big(\lnot p \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot r)\big)
\op\equiv\hints{left part: simplify using idempotence of $\;\land\;$;}\hint{right part: simplify using DeMorgan}
    \big(p \lor (q \land r)\big) \;\lor\; \lnot \big(p \lor (q \land r)\big)
\op\equiv\hint{excluded middle}
    \true
\endcalc$$

So both sides of the original equivalence are $\;\true\;$, making the equivalence true as well.

Answer (score 0):

$$
[((p∨q)∧¬(¬p∧(¬q∨¬r)))∨(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧¬r)]∨(p∨¬p) \\
[((p∨q)∧(p∨(q∧r)))∨(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧¬r)]∨(p∨¬p) \\
[((p∨q)∧((p∨q)∧(p∨r)))∨(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧¬r)]∨(p∨¬p) \\
[((p∨q)∧(p∨q)∧(p∨r))∨(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧¬r)]∨(p∨¬p) \\
[((p∨q)∧(p∨r))∨(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧¬r)]∨(p∨¬p) \\
[(p∨(q∧r))∨(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧¬r)]∨(p∨¬p) \\
(q∧r)∨(¬p∧¬q)∨(¬p∧¬r)∨(p∨¬p) \\
(q∧r)∨(¬p∧(¬q∨¬r))∨(p∨¬p) \\
(q∧r)∨(¬p∧¬(q∧r))∨(p∨¬p) \\
(((q∧r)∨¬p)∧((q∧r)∨¬(q∧r)))∨(p∨¬p) \\
(q∧r)∨¬p∨(p∨¬p) \\
(q∧r)∨(p∨¬p) \\
(q∧r)∨true \\
s∨true \\
true \\
(p∨¬p)
$$

reverse that up and put a $≡$ between each two lines.